# File recovery through Inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, recovery, inode

I am trying to do my final project, which involves restoring a deleted file through its inode.
I know bits and pieces of information about the whole topic but, don't seem to have any clear direction as to how to proceed.

So, could anyone kindly please direct me in this matter.

Comment: What bits and pieces do you know? Where are you specifically stuck or having problems? (We're not here to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Yes, thats true. I know the inode contains information about the file such as the data blocks , the size of the data blocks etc. and also, the super block contains info on the free list of inodes etc so, I guess I can check whether the deleted inode is present in the free inode list etc.

Comment: But, my problem is I dont know how to start it off. Am I suppose to write some kind of a kernel module that is called before we remove the file so that I can save the inode number somewhere or write a new command such as "remove" or somethin which does pretty much the same thing :P

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [Link to a specific inode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178593/link-to-a-specific-inode)?