# How do I create a directory with a specific inode number?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, ext3

How to create a directory in ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem with a specific inode number? 
I've seen a working answer for a file but I could not apply it to a directory. A solution based on the debugfs command would be nice but any technical solution is good.
 [Solution for a file by Rhymoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752822/how-do-i-create-a-file-with-a-specific-inode-number)

Comment: Should the solution work completely in the user space or are we allowed to use kernel modules, implement new ioctls and/or syscalls, and so on?