# how to merge 2 big files

Tags: linux, file, merge

Suppose I have 2 files with size of 100G each. And I want to merge them into one, and then delete them. In linux
we can use

cat file1 file2 > final_file

But that needs to read 2 big files, and then write a bigger file.  Is it possible just append one file to the other, so that no IO is required?  Since metadata of file contains the location of the file, and the length, I am wondering whether it is possible to change the metadata of the file to do the merge, so no IO will happen.

Comment: Someone who finds their way to this questions might find "hungrycat" useful. hungrycat prints contents of a file on the standard output, while simultaneously freeing disk space occupied by the file: https://github.com/jwilk/hungrycat

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Can you merge two files without writing one file onto the other?

**Only in obscure theory**.  Since disk storage is always based on blocks and filesystems therefore store things on block boundaries, you could only append one file to another without rewriting if the first file ended perfectly on a block boundary. There are some rare filesystem configurations that [use tail packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation), but that would only help if the first file where already using the tail block of the previous file.

Unless that perfect scenario occurs or your filesystem is able to mark a partial block in the middle of the file (I've never heard of this), this won't work. Just to kick the edge case around, there's also no way outside of changing the kernel interace to make such a call (re: [Link to a specific inode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1178593/90322))

### Can we make this better than doubling the size of both files?

**Yes**, we can use the append (`>>`) operation instead.

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

That will still result in using all the space of consumed by `file2` twice over until we can delete it.

### Can we avoid using extra space?

**No**. Unless somebody comes back with something I don't know, you're basically out of luck there. It's possible to [truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) a file, forgetting about the existence of the end of it, but there is no way to forget about the existence of the start unless we get back to modifying inodes directly and having to alter the kernel interface to the filesystem since that's definitely not a a POSIX operation.

### What about writing a little bit at a time, then deleting what we wrote?

**No again**. Since we can't chop the start of a file off, we'd have to rewrite everything from the point of interest all the way to the end of the file. This would be very costly for IO and only useful after we've already read half the file.

### What about sparse files?

**Maybe!** Sparse file allow us to store a long string of zeroes without using up nearly that much space. If we were to read `file2` in large chunks starting at the end, we could write those blocks to the end of `file1`. `file1` would immediately look (and read) as if it were the same size as both, but it would be corrupted until we were done because everything we hadn't written would be full of zeroes.

Explaining all this is another answer in itself, but if you can do a spare allocation, you would be able to use only your chunk read size + a little bit extra in disk space to perform this operation. For a reference talking about sparse blocks in the middle of files, see http://lwn.net/Articles/357767/ or do a search involving the term, `SEEK_HOLE`.

Why is this "maybe" instead of "yes"? Two parts: you'd have to write your own tool (at least we're on the right site for that), and sparse files are not universally respected by file systems and other processes alike. Fortunately you probably won't have to worry about other processes respecting your file, but you will have to worry about setting the right flags and making sure your filesystem is amenable. Last of all, you'll still be reading and re-writing the length of `file2`, which isn't what you want. This method does mean you can append with just a small amount of disk space, though, rather at using at least `2*file2` amount of space.

Comment: This deserves more votes.

Answer (score 8):

You can do like this

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

file1 will become the full content.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to merge (on Linux) two big files by working on their meta-data.

Maybe you might consider some kind of database for your work.

As Alexandre noticed, you can append one big file to another, but this still requires a lot of data copying.

Comment: The theorical way would be to change the mapping (files > blocks) in filesystem... maybe some filesystems have this kind of functions?

Comment: No, they don't have that, and if the files length is not a multiple of the filesystem block size, your solution won't work.

Comment: Yes I understand, every content from every blocks will need to be shifted to cover the gap.